# fcn_alexnet.caffemodel is not visible in standard segmentation network of DIGITS

Tags: nvidia-digits

I wanted to use NVIDIA DIGITS for image segmentation. According to this tutorial, https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/tree/master/examples/semantic-segmentation , I have created caffmodel named as 'fcn_alexnet.caffemodel'.

But, it is not showing on my DIGITS page. What shall I do to add this to DIGITS?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I am not too late to help. To use the "pretrained FCN-AlexNet", you need to follow exactly the instructions.

1. select the Custom Network tab
2. make sure the Caffe sub-tab is selected
3. copy/paste this prototxt (please refer to the link you had attached)
4. in Pretrained model(s) specify the path to the pre-trained FCN-Alexnet (*this need to be done)